# Is my equivalent op-amp for this circuit correct?

Tags: operational-amplifier

The following is a question from 8.18 in  *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 342.

Consider the circuit in this following figure. \$(\frac{W} {L})_{1-4} =\frac{50} {0.5} \$, \$|{I_D}_{1-4}| = 0.5\ \mathrm{mA}\$, \$R_2 = 3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}\$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Between M1 and M3,

$$(V_{in} - V_F) g_{m1} + \frac{V_x} {r_{o1}} = - \frac{V_x} {r_{o3}} $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_x} {V_{in} - V_F} = -g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3})$$

Between M2 and M4,
$$V_x  g_{m2} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}} = -\frac{V_{out}} {r_{o4}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} = -g_{m2} (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4})$$

$$A_{v,open} = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in} - V_F} = 
\frac{V_{out}} {V_x} \frac{V_x} {V_{in} - V_F}
  = g_{m1} g_{m2} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4})$$

$$\beta = \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$$

$$A_{v,close} = \frac{A_{v,open}} {1 + A_{v,open} \beta} =
\frac{g_{m1} g_{m2} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4})} {1 + g_{m1} g_{m2} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4}) \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}}$$

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Designalog However, when you use test voltage and break the loop. The open loop gain is different from what I got here.

Comment: Good job, but if you want to you could include the loading effect. See this example. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303105/series-shunt-feedback-amplifier-analysis-finding-loop-gain/303134#303134

Comment: And the open loop gain is \$ A_{OL} =\frac{r_{o3}}{(R_1||R_2)\:\frac{1}{g_{m1}}}\times g_{m2}\left((R_1 + R_2)||r_{O2}||r_{O4} \right)\$  If I include the loading effect.

Comment: @G36 Where do you break the loop?

Comment: What values did you choose for R1, ro1, ro2, ro3 and ro4?

Comment: @G36 Does the value of  R1, ro1, ro2, ro3 and ro4? matter? I am confused

Comment: @kile I think you picked a good point to break the loop there (at the gate). So, if your derivation is correct, you get an exact answer (more accurate than the loading effect in G36 answer).

Comment: @internet I think loading effect is more accurate. Do you have any proof? How do you draw a conclusion that my derivation is more accurate?

Comment: @kile check this: https://prnt.sc/LraMqxl5Jwd-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this equivalent circuit to find open-loop gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu7DKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Neglect \$r_{o1}\$ for this case.

$$ A_{OL} = \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}=\frac{r_{o3}}{(R_1||R_2)\: + \frac{1}{g_{m1}}}\times \frac{\left((R_1 + R_2)||r_{O2}||r_{O4} \right)}{\frac{1}{g_{m2}}}$$

Therefore, the closed-loop gain is

$$A_{CL} = \frac{A_{OL}}{1 + A_{OL}\beta} = $$

$$ \large A_{CL} = \frac{\frac{r_{o3}}{(R_1||R_2)\:\frac{1}{g_{m1}}}\times \frac{\left((R_1 + R_2)||r_{O2}||r_{O4} \right)}{\frac{1}{g_{m2}}}}{1 + \frac{r_{o3}}{(R_1||R_2)\:\frac{1}{g_{m1}}}\times \frac{\left((R_1 + R_2)||r_{O2}||r_{O4} \right)}{\frac{1}{g_{m2}}} \times \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}}$$

The values matter because we can compare the results and also justify the simplifications we made during the AOL derivation.

Comment: Thank you for your work!

Comment: internet thinks my solution is exact gain and more accurate than yours. Do you think so?

Comment: @kile G36's answer is great. But what I meant is that if you want to obtain the exact expression, this is not the one, as it ignores the forward propagation of the input signal through the feedback network. 
(https://prnt.sc/LraMqxl5Jwd-)

Comment: $$\frac{V_x} {V_{in}} = \frac{g_{m1}} {1/r_{o1} + 1/r_{o3} + (R_1 \parallel R_2) r_{o3} (g_{m1} + 1/r_{o1} )}$$

Comment: @G36 I think the answer will be this if you neglect \$r_{o1}\$.

$$\frac{V_x} {V_{in}} = \frac{r_{o3}} {R_1 \parallel R_2 + 1/g_{m1}}$$

Comment: Your first equation that includes ro1 for Vx/Vin is wrong (not correct). The exact solution will look something like this $$\frac{V_X}{V_{IN}} = \frac{g_{m1}\:r_{o3} \:r_{o1}}{ r_{o3}+ r_{o1} + (R_1||R_2) + g_{m1}\:r_{o1}(R_1||R_2)} $$

Comment: @G36 I I revise the  equation, and you equation is right. But you forgot to add minus - sign.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is my equivalent op-amp for this circuit correct?*

It's a very reasonable and usable approximation (as I hinted on one of your earlier questions). Vin is the non-inverting input and Vf is the inverting input. It has a gain of \$1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$.

The downside is that the output is not a push-pull stage but, there are many circuits that really wouldn't notice or care about that.

Comment: However, when  you use test voltage and break the loop. The open loop gain is different from what I got here.

Comment: @kile nothing is exactly the same. It will have an open-loop of possibly over a thousand and when you close the loop it will have a reliable (set by the two resistors) gain up to 50. It's as good as many op-amps. Open-loop it has no application that I can think of.